# Почему не обособлен оборот «по прогнозам ученых»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

В учебнике нашел такое предложение:

*Если в 1980 г. их численность составляла 4 млрд 456 млн, в 2000 г. — 6 млрд 80 млн, то **по прогнозам ученых** в 2020 г. население всего мира составит 7 млрд 518 млн человек*.

Почему не обособлен выделенный полужирным шрифтом оборот?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Если в 1980 г. их численность составляла 4 млрд 456 млн, в 2000 г. — 6 млрд 80 млн, то **по прогнозам ученых** в 2020 г. население всего мира составит 7 млрд 518 млн человек.*

Это обстоятельственный оборот, который в этом предложении **не обособляется**.

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ**

1. **О вводных словах**

**Вводные слова** — это как бы особая **метка автора**, указывающего на источник информации (в этой теме). Вводные слова не являются членами предложения.

Но этот же оборот может входить **в состав предложения** и выписываться в его интонационную структуру.

2. **Анализ предложения**

(1) Именно это мы и видим в данном случае. Рассмотрим **вторую часть** предложения:  *... **по прогнозам ученых** в / 2020 г. население всего мира /  составит 7 млрд 518 млн человек.*

(2) **Какой это член предложения?**

Это обстоятельственный **детерминант** в начале предложения (его обычная позиция). Детерминант относится не к определенному слову, а к предикативной **основе** предложения.

(3) **Какой зададим вопрос?**

Вопрос такой: ***в соответствии с чем?***  Население (что сделает?) увеличится до определенной величины. Это будущий прогноз, который может и не оправдаться.

(4) **Независимо от мнения ученых?**

Но ведь это всего лишь **версия**. И тогда по части семантики я не вижу здесь проблем.

**ВЫВОД**

Названный оборот речи в этом предложении по всем показателям (**семантика, грамматика, структура, интонация**)  выполняет функцию **обстоятельства**, а не вводного слова.

Этот вывод **соответствует** информации из Справочника по пунктуации.

**[Справочник по пунктуации](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_587)**

**ПО ПРОГНОЗАМ / РАСЧЕТАМ** (кого, чего, чьим), в составе вводного сочетания !

Не смешивать с употреблением **в роли члена предложения.** *Глупо строить планы на будущее по прогнозам астрологов*.

**Пример:** *Сейчас нас восемь миллиардов, а по прогнозам будет вдвое больше.*   **Тоже будем обособлять?**

Comment: *Именно это мы и видим в данном случае: По прогнозам ученых / к 2100 году / эта величина удвОится.* Простите, о каком ***данном*** случае Вы говорите? Это *часть* предложения из моего ответа. И там ***есть*** запятые.

Comment: Извините,  это случайность: предложение из вашего ответа очень похоже на заданное предложение.  Но приведенный вами пример – это все же не РОЗЕНТАЛЬ, поэтому не стоит считать его образцом для подражания. Правомерность поставленной запятой может вызывать сомнения. Зачем же списывать эту запятую из чужих ответов.

Comment: Так в вашем справочнике наоборот всегда ратуют за обособление

Comment: В справочнике предлагается два варианта: вводное слово и член предложения.  Для конкретного предложения надо провести анализ и сделать выбор.

Comment: Грамота приводит пример с членом предложения, там по-другому и не напишешь. В разбираемом же примере структура совсем не та. "**Если** составляла 4, **то** по прогнозам учёных составит 7". Не вяжется по семантике (ну, это моё мнение). Интонация здесь вообще на последнем месте, так как вводные часто вообще произносятся слитно с остальными словами. Так что, нигде не будем ставить запятые? По Розенталю, Лопатину и Грамоте наше "по прогнозам" - источник информации.

Comment: Там те еще жуки в этой Грамоте. Специально подобрали предложение с очевидной грамматической связью, Да только про неочевидное забыли.  И по части интонации у вас интересная точка зрения. Когда  он вам нужна, то и важна, а так не будем учитывать.  По большому счету вводные слова  –  это  тематические обособленные обороты, и они часто меняют свою роль.

Comment: А если так: "Весело здесь!  А по моим прогнозам будет еще веселее."  Обособить оборот? Как-то не хочется... Так что, всегда будем обособлять?

Comment: Некоторое время спустя ещë больше разобрался в этой теме, и ваш ответ тоже подходит. Принимаю.

Comment: Спасибо, Максим! Вы мне в чем-то напоминаете одного нашего участника. Риторика примерно та же.

Comment: @Sharon Какого, интересно? :)

Comment: @Sharon Извиняюсь, что так поздно подробнее узнал об этой теме (так бы вы хоть 50 репутации получили). Но я думаю, ничего страшного :)

Comment: @Максим Интересно, какого? Вам лучше не знать своего будущего))

Comment: @Sharon Ну как хотите. Может, вас действительно послушать нужно в этом плане)

Comment: @Максим  Хорошо, я задам еще один вопрос по этой теме, а то здесь уже писать негде.

Answer (score 4):

• Сначала решение "Грамоты".

> [**Вопрос № 311190**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C)
> ...а можно ли не обособлять обороты с первообразными предлогами, если ты не выделяешь их интонацией? Я даже в учебнике нашел такую фразу: «Если в 1980 г. их численность составляла 4 млрд 456 млн, в 2000 г. — 6 млрд 80 млн, то по прогнозам ученых в 2020 г. население всего мира составит 7 млрд 518 млн человек». Оборот «по прогнозам ученых» не выделен запятыми.
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
> Обороты, состоящие из существительного с предлогом, в целом не нуждаются в обособлении. Однако в некоторых случаях эти обороты выполняют особую функцию. Например, сочетание *по прогнозам ученых* из приведенного Вами предложения относится к группе вводных конструкций, указывающих на источник сообщения, и, соответственно, ***должно быть обособлено***.

• Затем немного правил:

[**по прогнозам**](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/518/%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC), вводное слово
Выделяется знаками препинания, обычно запятыми, вместе с относящимися к нему словами.
***По прогнозам специалистов,** цены на нефть вырастут. Сборная России, **по прогнозам аналитиков,** попадет на следующий чемпионат мира по футболу.*

• Потом разбор предложения:

*Если в 1980 г. их численность составляла 4 млрд 456 млн, в 2000 г. — 6 млрд 80 млн, то **по прогнозам ученых** в 2020 г. население всего мира составит 7 млрд 518 млн человек.*

Попробуем задать вопрос к сочетанию "по прогнозам ученых": составит — *на каком основании? на основании чего? почему? по какой причине? каким образом?*
Ни один из этих вопросов не подходит, потому что население мира все равно вырастет до семи с чем-то миллиардов — независимо от мнения ученых.
Собственно **прогнозы** ученых на рождаемость не влияют.
И пауза есть — **после** оборота.

• Обязательно примеры:

***По прогнозам ученых,** в будущем Петербургу могут угрожать куда более сильные наводнения* (А. М. Городницкий. Тайны и мифы науки. В поисках истины);
*Уже сейчас численность проживающего в этом климатическом поясе населения превышает 3 миллиарда человек, а, **по прогнозам ученых,** к 2100 году эта величина удвоится* (Александр Волков. На полпути от Миллениума).

■ **Вывод**: ставим запятые.
*По прогнозам ученых* — это вводная конструкция, указывающая на источник информации.

Comment: Этот вопрос я  и задавал «Грамоте». И я так скажу: необязательно всë, что говорит «Грамота», — правда. В РАНе — что более официальный справочник, чем «Грамота»,  — написано, что выделяется только ввиду интонации и нахождение между главными членами. Так что здесь нет интонации, если не обособлено.

Comment: Дело ведь не только в "Грамоте", но и во мнении, высказанном в нейтральном (не относящемся к "Грамоте"), официальном словаре-справочнике. (https://market.yandex.ru/product--v-m-pakhomov-v-v-svintsov-i-v-filatova-trudnye-sluchai-russkoi-punktuatsii-slovar-spravochnik/1781761771?cpa=1) А вопрос, заданный на "Грамоте", интересен всем — чтобы было понятно, о чем речь собственно (там ведь нигде не отмечено, что он ваш).

Answer (score 1):

Оборот не обособлен потому, что он не имеет интонационного выделения. А они выделяются только в этом случае и когда стоят между подлежащим и сказуемым. Так написано [в этом справочнике](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=192).

Только «Грамота» не упоминает интонационного выделения и говорит о невыделении только ввиду вхождения в состав сказуемого. Но этот сайт не является официальным, поэтому во всëм полагаться на неë не стоит.

Вывод: нет интонационного выделения.

Comment: Максим, конечно, во всём полагаться не стоит, в ответах Грамоты бывают ошибки (причём они их исправляют). Но что значит "не является официальным"? Самый что ни на есть официальный. А Лопатин, на который вы ссылаетесь, РАН и Грамота "повязаны". Вот, например, комментарий Sharon: "Это основной ресурс, которым пользуются все. Ему-то как раз и нужно доверять в первую очередь. Там все материалы постоянно обновляются, он в первую очередь связан с академическими кругами".

Comment: РАН не Грамота, а Грамота не РАН,  Нельзя считать Справочную службу официальным источником.  В справочнике по пунктуации (это тоже Грамота.ру) предлагается два варианта: вводное слово и член предложения.  Для конкретного предложения надо провести анализ и сделать выбор.  И мы уже видели, как они обращаются с грамматикой в теме расчленения союза. Довольно-таки свободно, по своему усмотрению.

Comment: Так что не стоит всегда строиться по их команде.  У Розенталя и Лопатина нет этого оборота в теме вводных слов.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Я согласен с Sharon. «Грамота» не имеет никакого официального статуса. Она тоже придумывает свои правила насчет, как уже и сказали, расчленения союзов, а также, как я уже заметил, оборотов с производными предлогами. К этому ресурсу, конечно, можно прислушиваться, но не во всëм. РАН больше похож на правду, да и там лингвисты настоящие работают, нежели чем на «Грамоте». Так что РАН, определëнно, более правдивый ресурс.

Comment: @Sharon А кто строится? Я же говорю, что формулировка "не является официальным" некорректна, сайт официально зарегистрирован в "высших эшелонах". А параграф Лопатина не совсем по теме.

Comment: Ученые дают прогноз численности населения. В соответствии с этим прогнозом указывается численность населения. Какое же это вводное слово?  Конкретную цифру назвали ученые. Это основное сообщение. Также  обратите внимание на структуру предложения: названы два года и две цифры. Это ни о чем не говорит?   Сейчас так, а по прогнозам будет столько.

Comment: @Sharon  Комментарий под вашим ответом.